# Query builder Column alias, without any column in Kohana Framework?

Tags: php, kohana, query-builder

like you can do in a normal query:

```
SELECT id, 'Default' AS Type FROM ...
```

I would like to do that in Kohana, i tried:

```
    DB::select('id', array('Default', 'Type'))->from('...')
```

But it thinks that "Default" is a column so it returns with error unknown column Default.

What can i do here to make a alias of my own defined column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DB::expr` for this:

```
DB::select('id', DB:expr("'Default' AS Type"))->from('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it thinks that "Default" is a column so it returns with error unknown column Default.

Not using Kohana, but couldn't you enclose it in double quotes, e.g.:

```
DB::select('id', array("'Default'", 'Type'))->from('...')
```